# Flash support for Jellybean (4.1)

Tags: adobe-flash, 4.1-jelly-bean

Adobe has released statements saying they will no longer support flash for newer Android builds starting with 4.1.

I flashed a custom rom of 4.1 the other day and couldn't find any 3rd party flash support in the market. I use flash for [Orb](http://orb.com) to stream tv. Orb has an Android app but it unusable and all around horrible experience (verified by the the many negative reviews) but you could use the website to stream flash as a work around to the poor app which worked great.

**My question is: how can I play flash video in Android Jellybean (4.1)**

Comment: Flash is closed and fairly complex, you're not likely to ever find a third-party implementation (apart from partial implementations like Flash Lite).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Currently](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=28039970&postcount=2), you can side load the flash player on a 4.1 device. Meaning you have to download the apk file and install directly from the device, or with adb. There is no guarantee that flash will work at all in the future. Not only is Adobe dropping flash support for Android 4.1, No new installs for any version of android will be allowed for the Flash Player app from Google Play after August 15th.

I hope that this actually means that Adobe is moving closer to making flash "export" to something that modern browsers can all run, like using the HTML5 canvas. Flash on Android has always been pretty limited. It's only real use was for playing flash video, anything else I ever tried to use it with was buggy and laggy.

Comment: Guide can be found here: http://www.androidauthority.com/adobe-flash-new-jelly-bean-devices-how-you-can-still-get-it-110070/ and here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1774336