# Flash Player does not work on Android 4.0 and upwards

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, adobe-flash

[image: error on android phone flash]

Please check my attached about Flash Player error on my android phone. I can see Utube, Facebook videos very well but some of the website showing like that error. How could I solve this problem?

Phone : Huawei U9200 P1
Version : ICS 4.0.3
Flash Player Ver : Adobe Air and Adobe Flash Player 11.1

Comment: Flash support is officially dropped for Android platforms, and also, not compatible with ICS upwards.

Comment: However, some browsers are experimenting with Flash built in. I believe Firefox Mobile does.

Comment: The reason YouTube and Facebook videos are working for you is because they're _not_ using Flash.

Comment: See: [Is Adobe Flash deprecated with regards to Android Devices and Apps?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/39751/16575) / [Flash support for Jellybean (4.1)](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/25724/16575) / [How can I use Flash Player now that it's no longer supported?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/32948/16575) and other [Adobe Flash questions](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=adobe+flash).